# Activity-Fragment communicating: cluttering

Tags: android, android-fragments

To communicate stuff to your hosting `Activity`, the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) suggest to let your `Activity` implement some interface, and cast it to that interface in your `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

However, if your `Activity` is a host to many `Fragment`s, your `Activity` declaration will look something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ListenerA, ListenerB, ListenerC /* etcetera */
```

Of course, this does not help readability, modularity etc, let alone just stuffing all the implemented methods in the `Activity`'s body itself.

Is there a better way of achieving this?
If I recall correctly, manually setting a listener to the `Fragment` is advised against, although I cannot find a source for this.

Comment: I would like to know this as well; although I don't see a problem with the suggested approach (using interfaces). If you have too many implementations, you might as well redesign the app to make it uncluttered.

Comment: The whole idea of `Fragment`s is to create reusable, modular components for your app, making multiple `Activity`'s unnecessary (is it?). I've seen cases where the number of interfaces would grow upto 10-15, causing a very cluttered `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could achieve communication that i could think of but i they might be bad practice so take it with a pinch of salt!

The first method would be to use getActivity() to get a reference to a activity method which updates it. You just have to be careful that that the fragments activity reference isn't currently null.

The second is using broadcasts to notify the activity that something has changed and use a broadcast receiver to perform different actions depending on the broadcast received. (Seems a little overkill).

Comment: I thought about those options as well. The first defies the purpose of  loose coupling where the `Fragment` shouldn't know anything about its hosts. The second option indeed seems a little overkill, but debatable.

Comment: Using a `LocalBroadcastManager`, the overhead isn't that big at all. It seems more robust than the original method.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I would suggest is to use EventBus :
**EventBus allows publish-subscribe-style communication between components without requiring the components to explicitly register with one another**

Other approach is to create custom fragment and make it abstract and add a abstract listener method.. like below

```
public abstract class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onFragmentClick(); 
        }
    });
    return row;
}

public abstract void onFragmentClick();
}
```

and when you create the instance of custom fragment, implement the listener method as..

```
CustomFragment  customFragment = new CustomFragment() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentClick() {

        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the `EventBus`. I'm not so sure about the abstract `Fragment` though.

Comment: Fine,I have used both the approach in my previous project. Abstract Fragment is easier to maintain the code than EventBus.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can be to copy the style of some android components like, for example, onClickListener which has the method onClick(View v) and it doesn't consider how many views are being listened for the activity, it delegates to the activity to choose what is the current one.

For example:

```
public interface onSomethingHappenedInFragmentListener{
    public void onSomethingHappened(Fragment f);
}
```

In your activity:

```
myFragment1.setOnSomethingHappenedInFragmentListener(this);
myFragment2.setOnSomethingHappenedInFragmentListener(this);
myFragment3.setOnSomethingHappenedInFragmentListener(this);
myFragment4.setOnSomethingHappenedInFragmentListener(this);
```

and in your activity's implementation of `onSomethingHappened`:

```
public void onSomethingHappened(Fragment f){
    switch(f.getID()){
    myFragment1.getID():
    myFragment2.getID():
    myFragment3.getID():
    myFragment4.getID():
    ...
    }
}
```

and then in your activity you can check which is the fragment that has changed.

With this you can have N fragments with only one listener, please note that the interface is an example, in real situations maybe you need to add some extra information to the method parameters

Comment: This still clutters up your `Activity` with possibly 10+ `implements` clauses and it's methods.

Comment: You will implement only one interface. for sure you need to implement as many code as fragments you have, it's the only way to know what to do with each fragment.

Comment: Ah, like that. I missed the general interface part. Could be an interesting solution, but also tricky to figure out *what* exactly happened.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a little bit poor, I've edited it to be more clear